# Finding values in a number of columns using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am relatively new to excel vba, but I am looking for some advice about creating a macro that I can run over a number of worksheets in a workbook.

The advice I am looking for is to take 3 columns where I can find certain values in those columns. Where a row has a value in each of those 3 columns that is met to save those rows along with all the column headings into a new worksheet in the same workbook. So, if I have 10 worksheets in my workbook and run the macro, I need to end up with 20 worksheets.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You can start experimenting with .Find :) See this link. http://siddharthrout.wordpress.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/ Once you get that part right start recording a macro to move values between sheets and then combine the 2 codes :) Give it a try and then if you get stuck, simply post back...

Answer (score 0):

Since you are new to VBA, I'm giving you some code. Lord knows I had plenty of help when I was new. Check this out. I am not sure how you are going to pass which values to look for, but this should give you a great start.

```
Sub find3_makesheet()

Dim strValue As String
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range

strValue = "myValue"

For Each wks In Worksheets

    With wks

        If Not .Columns(1).Find(strValue, lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then Set rng1 = .Columns(1).Find(strValue, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not .Columns(2).Find(strValue, lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then Set rng2 = .Columns(2).Find(strValue, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not .Columns(2).Find(strValue, lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then Set rng3 = .Columns(2).Find(strValue, lookat:=xlWhole)

        If Not rng1 Is Nothing And Not rng2 Is Nothing And Not rng3 Is Nothing Then
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
            Set wksCopyTo = ActiveSheet
            .Rows(1).EntireRow.Copy wksCopyTo.Rows(1)
            rng1.EntireRow.Copy wksCopyTo.Rows(2)
            rng2.EntireRow.Copy wksCopyTo.Rows(3)
            rng3.EntireRow.Copy wksCopyTo.Rows(4)
        End If

    End With

    Set rng1 = Nothing
    Set rng2 = Nothing
    Set rng3 = Nothing
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Solution was helpful, but I need help tweaking it because I am not looking at columns individually but altogether

Comment: Well...  First thing I would do is explain to yourself in English what exactly you want to do -> I know this seems kind of redundant, but it's valuable to write the code out (similar to how I have done above) in English. Then do some searching to figure out how to do that in VBA. The above code should help a lot with structure and maybe syntax. That said, make an attempt to do what you want and if you get stuck, post your efforts back and we can help you get unstuck.